# Recursion with multiple variables

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I am a Prolog newbie, sorry for the trivial question.

Let's consider the following code:

```
at(X, Y, 0) :- 
  X =:=1, 
  Y =:=1,
  !.
at(X, Y, S) :- 
  S \== 0, 
  at(XP, Y, SP), 
  S is SP + 1, 
  X is XP + 1.
```

When running `at(1, 1, 1)`, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
>   ERROR: In:
>   ERROR:   [10] _2090=:=1
>   ERROR:    [9] at(_2116,2,0) at /tmp/d.pl:1
>   ERROR:    [8] at(1,2,1) at /tmp/d.pl:2
>   ERROR:    [7]

I understand the error, but I cannot find a solution to that.

I have also used `at(1, 1, 0).` but in this case it stack overflows.

Obviously, the snippet of code is a simplified version of my project.
For this reason, I cannot simply rethink the `at` predicate as follows:

```
at(X, Y, S) :- 
  Y =:= 1, 
  X =:= S + 1.
```

How can I fix the `at` predicate without completely rethinking the implementation, provided that it is feasible?

Thanks for your help.

As requested by @lurker, I am adding more details about the original problem I am facing.
Basically, I am trying to implement a reasoning system using Prolog to solve [Wumpus world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus).
I posed a restriction on which features I could use in Prolog: **no** `assert*` and related instructions.

The basic idea was to define a variable S, which is the status of the system and it is the input for most of the functions.
Then I tried to implement the function that defines *where the agent is at a certain status of the system*.

This is my last (buggy) version of my `at` function:

```
at(1, 1, S) :- S =:= 0, !.
at(X, Y, S) :-
    writef('Am I at %w, %w at status %w?\n', [X, Y, S]),
    (
        S \== 0,
        (
            at(XP, Y, SP), forwarded(XP, Y, SP), direction(XP, Y, 0, SP), S is SP + 1, X is XP + 1, X > 0, !;
            at(X, YP, SP), forwarded(X, YP, SP), direction(X, YP, 1, SP), S is SP + 1, Y > 0, Y is YP + 1, !;
            at(XP, Y, SP), forwarded(XP, Y, SP), direction(XP, Y, 2, SP), S is SP + 1, X is XP - 1, !;
            at(X, YP, SP), forwarded(X, YP, SP), direction(X, YP, 3, SP), S is SP + 1, Y is YP - 1, !
        ),
        writef('--------> I am at %w, %w, status %w\n', [X, Y, S])
    );
    (writef('--------> I am NOT at %w, %w, status %w\n', [X, Y, S]), fail).
```

The above snippet refers to two additional functions:

1. `forwarded/3`: it is true if the agent, at a certain status, decided to move towards the current direction
2. `direction/4`: it is true if the agent, at a certain status (and position... well probably I could remove such variables from this function. Not sure indeed...) has a specific direction

So the basic idea, for instance, is that if the agent is at (1, 1), direction 0 at status 0 (direction can be 0, 1, 2, 3, respectively, right, up, left, down), then at status 1 it is at (2, 1).

Since the agent wins if it holds the gold and it is at the starting point, my goal function is:

```
win(S) :- hold_gold(S), X is 1, Y is 1, at(X, Y, S).
```

If I invoke the interpreter and write `win(S)` (I'd like to know at which status the agent wins), it goes to infinite recursion. 
As above written, I understand the reason but I cannot see a way to model the problem in Prolog. I would not know how to define the whole reasoning structure as it appeared to be quite straightforward.

Thanks.

Comment: You make a recursive call with `at(XP, Y, SP)`, but `XP` is a variable, and hence `XP =:= 1` fails.

Comment: What is your intention with the expression, `X = XP + 1`? If you're trying to check if `X` has a value that is equal to an evaluation of `XP + 1`, then this won't work since `=/2` is the unification operator.

Comment: @lurker sorry my mistake, I fixed that. I still have the problem though...

Comment: @willem-van-onsem thanks for the answer, yes I understand that but I don't know how to reframe the problem without completely rethinking it (see the last snippet of code)

Comment: `at(X, Y, 0) :- X =:=1, 
  Y =:=1,
  !.` will only work if `X` and `Y` are bound since `=:=/2` requires that the arguments be bound. It checks whether two expressions evaluate to the same value. You should use `at(1, 1, 0).` instead. THEN solve the stack overflow issue some other way since it's not really fixed in either case. The error just prevents the code from going further. Your logic does not have a proper termination check. You haven't said what the logic really means. You've only said, *consider the following code*. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @lurker thanks for the answer. Basically, I am trying to solve the 'Wumpus world' without using 'assertz' or 'asserta': the idea would be to have a status variable S, which starts from 0 and, upon any action of the agent, it increases. So, for instance, the position of the agent would be, at a state S, the same as at status S - 1 (SP), provided that the agent moved forward at the status S - 1.

Comment: @lurker thanks for the answer. Basically, I am trying to solve the 'Wumpus world' without using 'assertz' or 'asserta': the idea would be to have a status variable S, which starts from 0 and, upon any action of the agent, it increases. So, for instance, the position of the agent would be, at a state S, a step after the one at status S - 1 (SP), provided that the agent moved forward at the status S - 1.

Comment: The only condition for termination is your base case `at(1, 1, 0).` which can never be achieved when starting with the query, `at(1, 1, 1).` Try doing `trace.` before the query and observe the behavior.

Comment: @lurker agreed, what I would like to find is an approach to this class of problems. I cannot figure out how to achieve that result.

Comment: Assuming that the original problem (before writing it as Prolog) is logical and has proper termination conditions, then it's a matter of correctly writing the Prolog to align with it. I suspect that your Prolog implementation is just not correctly reflecting the actual problem. What exactly is the *expected* or desired behavior of `at/3`?

Comment: @lurker added details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @lurker in the end I gave up and used assertz/asserta. Everything was far smoother. Thanks again for your support.